# Is Islamic divorce enough to get re-married, or do I need an English civil divorce, too?

Tags: nikah, talaq, husband-wife

Asslamualikum

It's been three years since I'm having problems in my marriage. Every time I mention this to someone, they ignore me. I have done so much for my husband more than his expectations and now he treats me like trash I have been talking to him for years and years still no change?

I live in England. I have been married in both ways: Islamic and civil. My husband has never mentioned he wants to divorce me, but in every situation whenever I ask him whether he's going to divorce me, he keeps on saying "I will divorce you but first I need to sort out my problems before I can sort out yours."

Basically, he didn't give me anything when we got married, like gold or money. So he's basically preparing for all that, but I have doubt that he is saying all this just to keep me quiet. For two years, I've been  telling him to divorce me, but every time, he always has this answer ready: "I will divorce you." He never seems to be bothered about it. Whenever I ask him, he would just talk around the bush, or he would just ignore everything.

I've spoken to his family about how I feel, the reasons why I want a divorce, and my situation. They are not bothered either. I don't know, but I got a feeling that my husband's and his family's intentions aren't too good or positive.

**Question:** I just want to ask if I can get married again if I only had the Islamic divorce, will the marriage be legal? Or will I need the English civil divorce also? After I get married, I can apply for the English divorce.